# Java Error when receiving multiple inputs in IntelliJ

Tags: java, input, jetbrains-ide

I'm having trouble receiving 2 user inputs back to back. When I run the code below, it doesn't register the 2nd line. If I receive it as `int a = Integer.valueof(reader.nextLine());` it gives an error.

Basically it skips over second input. If I put a `println` between 2 inputs no there is no issue but this code works fine with other IDEs.

Is there a problem with IntelliJ or am I doing something wrong?

```java
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Input two strings");
String a = reader.nextLine();
String b = reader.nextLine();

System.out.println("you wrote " + a + " " + b);
```

Code as integer:
[image: Code as integer]

Error:
[image: It's error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the documentation of the `nextLine()` method states

> Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped. **This method returns the rest of the current line, excluding any line separator at the end**. [...]

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()

Pressing the enter key corresponds to inputting two characters: a new line (\n) and a carriage return (\r). Both of these are line separators. When you type your first input and then press enter, the `Scanner` returns the first line, stops and then awaits for the second input (your second `nextLine()` invocation). However, since there is already a line terminator (the second line terminator left from the previous read), once you enter your second input, your scanner immediately halts at the beginning and returns an empty `String`.

What you need to do is to get rid of that "extra" line terminator character with a `nextLine()` placed in between the first and second read.

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Input two strings");
String a = reader.nextLine();
reader.nextLine();
String b = reader.nextLine();

System.out.println("you wrote " + a + " " + b);
```

Alternatively, you can ask for the input with two print messages. In fact, the second print will move the `Scanner`'s internal cursor forward (as the program has written some text on screen), skipping the second line terminator and retrieving your input correctly:

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Input the first string");
String a = reader.nextLine();
System.out.println("Input the second string");
String b = reader.nextLine();

System.out.println("you wrote " + a + " " + b);
```

Comment: thanks. I did figure out this solution. My problem was when done like this and put in other IDE this time it took 3 inputs instead of 2 and print out 1st and 3rd one. Thats why I wasn't keen on using but I guess there is no work around.